# if $a-b<e$ and $c-d<e$ prove: $\min\{a,c\}-\min\{b,d\}<e$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a conversation with chatGPT he claimed:

Given:
$\min\{a,c\}−\min\{b,d\}<(b−\min\{b,d\})+e$

Now, we know that
$b − \min\{
b
,
d
\}
\ge
0$, $b−\min\{b,d\}≥0$ because
$\min
⁡
\{
b
,
d
\}
\min{b,d}$ is the smaller value between
$b$ and
$d$. Therefore, we can simplify the expression:

$\min
⁡
\{
a
,
c
\}
−
\min
⁡
\{
b
,
d
\}
<
e
\min\{a,c\}−\min\{b,d\}<e$

But I don't agree with what he did? am I right?

---

The main question was how to prove the following:

if $a-b<e$ and $c-d<e$ prove: $\min\{a,c\}-\min\{b,d\}<e$.

Comment: What did ChatGPT claim? Use `>` to highlight that

Comment: What exactly do you not agree with? Please be specific.

Comment: ChatGPT is meant to string words together in a human-like fashion. It's not meant for math.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$ the claim follows from $a-b < e$.
The same holds if $c \leq a$ and $d \leq b$.

Now suppose $a \leq c$ and $d \leq b$. Then
$$\min \{a,c\} - \min \{b,d\} = a - d = a-c +c -d = (a-c) + (c-d) < 0 + e = e.$$

All that is left is to prove the remaining case where $c \leq a$ and $b \leq d$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can understand/justify the phrase "Without loss of generality, $\min\{b,d\}=b$," then the rest of the proof is one short sequence:

$$\min\{a,c\} - \min\{b,d\} = \min\{a,c\} - b \leq a-b < e$$

*Symmetry is useful.*